# XMLHttpRequest() reports file exists, although it is NOT there

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

For some days of my browser diary program, I want to play a Song-of-the-Day file (mp3), so I check whether file exists, and program 'works', except that XMLHttpRequest() returns status == 200 (meaning file exists) also for files (filenames) that don't exist.
At the moment I only have a file for 1st Jan, named 0101.mp3, so only for that day I want to display an icon to show that there is a song available.
Relevant part:

```
function check4Sotd(month, day) {
    var sotd = 'mydocs/sotd/' + pad(month) + pad(day) + '.mp3'; // pad puts leading zeroes, thus file for 1 Jan. will be 0101.mp3
    var sotdexists = false;         // assume there is no Song-of-the-Day file
    const myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();  
    myReq.open('HEAD', sotd, false);   
    myReq.send();  
    console.log(sotd + " --- " + myReq.status);
    if (myReq.status == 200) {      // then the mp3 file exists
        sotdexists = true;
    }
    /*  Some other stuff  */
    if(sotdexists) {
        $("#sotdIcon").show();      // show Song-of-the-Day icon
    }
};
```

Output on console for some example dates:

```
mydocs/sotd/0113.mp3 --- 404
mydocs/sotd/0112.mp3 --- 404
mydocs/sotd/0111.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0110.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0109.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0108.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0101.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/1231.mp3 --- 404
mydocs/sotd/1230.mp3 --- 404
mydocs/sotd/1201.mp3 --- 404
mydocs/sotd/0201.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0202.mp3 --- 404
mydocs/sotd/0102.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0131.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0121.mp3 --- 200
mydocs/sotd/0120.mp3 --- 404
```

Only file 0101.mp3 should give a status of 200.
I also tried changing filename to song0101.mp3 but that test gave same result.
You can see that there is a certain pattern in the status 200 lines.
What is going on here ?
Thanks for any help !

===============
Thanks Titus for your quick reply.
The relevant part of my code now looks like this:

```
const myReq = new XMLHttpRequest();  
myReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log(sotd + " -- " + this.readyState + " -- " + this.status);
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        sotdexists = true;
    }
};
myReq.open('HEAD', sotd, false);   
myReq.send();
```

and the log still shows the same problem:

```
mydocs/sotd/0113.mp3 -- 1 -- 0
mydocs/sotd/0113.mp3 -- 4 -- 404
mydocs/sotd/0112.mp3 -- 1 -- 0
mydocs/sotd/0112.mp3 -- 4 -- 404
mydocs/sotd/0111.mp3 -- 1 -- 0
mydocs/sotd/0111.mp3 -- 4 -- 200
mydocs/sotd/0110.mp3 -- 1 -- 0
mydocs/sotd/0110.mp3 -- 4 -- 200
mydocs/sotd/0109.mp3 -- 1 -- 0
mydocs/sotd/0109.mp3 -- 4 -- 200
mydocs/sotd/0101.mp3 -- 1 -- 0
mydocs/sotd/0101.mp3 -- 4 -- 200
mydocs/sotd/0129.mp3 -- 1 -- 0
mydocs/sotd/0129.mp3 -- 4 -- 404
```

but still only the file mydocs/sotd/0101.mp3 exists, so why the status 200 for the others ?

​

Comment: You're not using `XMLHttpRequest` correctly, you have to wait for [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) `4` (DONE)

Comment: Hi Titus thanks !  Changed the code, but still the same problem....

Comment: Are you using a server application ? If that is the case, maybe the server application's configuration is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, no, not that I'm aware of. Changed filename to abc0101def.mp3, but still same result.